# Получение местонахождения в службе

Tags: java, android

Я получал местонахождение в `Activity` путем имлементирования `LocationListener`, переопределив метод `onLocationChanged()`,

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
    addMarker();
}
```

Но этот вариант срабатывает если приложение запущен и этот `Activity` на фокусе.
Погуглив я нашел много вариантов. Некоторые требуют каких то не понятных классов, другие то gms.Location, то android.Location и с ошибками. В результате так и не понял какой из них актуальный и правильный, так как написаны 3-4 года назад.

Так вот, хотелось бы понять как получать местонахождение каждые 15 сек, именно в `сервисе`, и при запуске приложения брал данные от `сервиса`?

Answer (score 0):

Реализуете свой класс наследник от `IntentService`, где в методе `onHandleIntent()` реализуете логику определения локации. Результат выставляете в виде Broadcast'а, который надо ловить в приложении, через `BroadcastReceiver`

Обращение к сервису очень простое:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
startService(i);
```